How to make Windows (Screen) Magnifier follow text as it is being typed?
My eyesite is getting a lot worse, so I am using Window Magnifier (on Windows 11) to make things easier to read on my computer screen. Using my keyboard, I simply press the Windows button and (+) or (-) to zoom in or out.
When I use Notepad++, WordPad, or even Firefox, the Magnifier will follow the text as I type. This is very convenient, as it enables me to not have to keep manually moving the magnifier as I type.
Whenever I make Java GUI's using Swing, I notice that this behaviour is not present. Is there anyway to get the same thing for Java Swing GUI's? Considering the vast majority of my applications have the ability to do this, I strongly suspect that Java can too, and I am just missing a flag or something.
Here is an example code. When I type, the magnifier does not follow the text, and the text I am typing is eventually off-screen, forcing me to relocate the magnifier to see what I am typing.
import javax.swing.text.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public final class Daily
{

   public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {final Daily daily = new Daily();}
   public Daily() throws Exception
   {

      _20241214_text_box();

   }

   public static void _20241214_text_box()
   {

      SwingUtilities
         .invokeLater
         (
            () ->
            {

               final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
               frame.setSize(800, 800);
               frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
               frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

               final JTextComponent textBox =
                  // new JTextField()
                  new JTextArea()
                  ;
               frame.add(textBox);

               frame.setVisible(true);

            }
         )
         ;

   }

}


Did you enable access bridge ? If yes, note that Swing is pretty old and probably outdated (Tell me if I'm wrong, but I think it hasn't been really updated for ages), so maybe you should consider using another newer framework.

I suspect that your Swing GUI is larger than the screen dimensions when using Windows magnifier.  Maybe a DocumentListener that checks if the cursor is "off screen" and moves the JFrame  might work.  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, Creating a GUI With Swing.  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.

Swing components do not work properly with Windows Magnifier  Reported 28 July 2004.  The changes to the display are invisible to Swing.  I tried using the Toolkit class and a PropertyChangeListener.

I had actually thought it might be possible to add a CaretListener and use java.lang.foreign to invoke Windows’s MagSetFullscreenTransform and MagSetInputTransform functions, but it turns out MagSetInputTransform requires elevated privileges.

@GilbertLeBlanc That bug report says future project. I think I will re-raise the issue with them. Maybe now is future enough for them to try? Especially now that Java has released the FFI feature.

@QuentinC I did not, but it appears that Gilbert's link implies that it won't work either way. Still, worth a shot if you could link me to how to do it. I see (what appears to be) a few different ways to do it, and I am not sure which is correct.

@VGR Is there no way for Java to get that elevated access? My applications are all going to be JPackage'd and then sent out as .msi or .exe installs. So, ideally, if it is just as simple as "Run as Admin", that shouldn't be too hard to advise users to do.

UPDATE -- I started a discussion on the OpenJDK Mailing List. Hopefully the maintainers of Swing are convinced to add this feature in now, since they said it was a "Future Project". Here is the link -- https://mail.openjdk.org/pipermail/client-libs-dev/2024-December/025229.html

I’m honestly not sure.  I tried starting a command window as Administrator and then ran a test program from there, and it still got an Access Denied error.

Still, worth a shot if you could link me to how to do it. ==> Sadly, I can't help further. First because I'm totally blind and so can't test a screen magnifier at all, and second because I have stopped working with Java Swing  and using Java for GUI programs long time ago (15+ years) because it was very slow with screen readers anyway. Now I'm primarily using WXWidgets, but I don't think there's a Java port.

@VGR No worries, ty anyways. Nothing yet on the mailing lists, but it is the holidays season.

@QuentinC No worries, ty anyways. I will wait on the mailing list to see if they respond at all. I will also try JavaFX and see what I can do.

It would be interesting to know if there's accessibility support for JavaFX. I have never used it, but very quickly I don't have the impression that there is.

@QuentinC Disappointing, but it makes sense. Btw, someone from the OpenJDK community said they would take a look at it not even an hour ago. No promises they said, but this is a good sign. Check the link above to the mailing list.
